# infinite scroll with pagination demo

Tags: javascript, seo, infinite-scroll

here is a live example of infinite scroll

http://scrollsample.appspot.com/

which works fine and I want to use it for my website too. But what I can't understand is

by scrolling up or down in `head` area the links

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/..." />
<link rel="next" href="...."/>
<link rel="prev" href="...."/>
```

are updated automatically, can someone please guide me where it is heppening in JavaScript I can't find such updates.

Comment: Not a structured question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how it is done on this site but you can go with this:
[jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) and if you use [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) for the URL you can change the url without the hashtags.